# Combine data from two topics using Spring KafkaStreams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am working on a solution where I have to combine data from two Kafka topics t1 and t2.

t1 will consist first half of message and t2 the second half.

 e.g. If the full message is "a1b1c1d1" and "a2b2c2d2" then

t1 will have "a1b1" and "a2b2"

t2 will have "c1d1" and "c2d2"

 and I have to perform union on them to generate "a1b1c1d1" and "a2b2c2d2"

Since the message will not be in sequence I was planning to store in KStream store and combine the message when they become available.

Now the question, is this a good solution if yes is there an example.

```
@Component
public class MyViews {

    @Autowired
    public void buildProductView(StreamsBuilder sb) {
        sb.stream("products", Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.serdeFrom(Product.class)))
                .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(v.getId(), v))
                .toTable(Materialized.<Integer, Product, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("products-view")
                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.Integer())
                        .withValueSerde(Serdes.serdeFrom(Product.class)));
    }

    @Autowired
    public void buildPriceView(StreamsBuilder sb) {
        sb.stream("prices", Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.serdeFrom(Price.class)))
                .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(v.getId(), v))
                .toTable(Materialized.<Integer, Price, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("prices-view")
                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.Integer())
                        .withValueSerde(Serdes.serdeFrom(Price.class)));
    }

    @Data
    private class Product {
        Integer id;
        String item;
    }

    @Data
    private class Price {
        Integer id;
        Integer price;
    }

    @Data
    private class Order{
        Integer id;
        String item;
        Integer price;
    }
}
```

This is what I want to achieve

 whenever a message is published to "orders" topic I want to check whether corresponding ID exists in "prices-view", if it does then I will combine them to generate a "Order" object.

 similarly when a message is published to "prices" topic I want to check "products-view"

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "half"? As in, you are union-ing fields between topics? Or you have, say 100 messages total, you consume 50 records from one topic, then 50 from another? Also, please share the code you've written so far and better explain what you're combining

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer Update the question with an example, I will be union-ing fileds between topics.

Comment: Do these strings have the same keys? Have you otherwise read the Kafka Streams documentation on joins? https://kafka.apache.org/30/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#joining

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for the link, I update the question with an example.

Comment: Did you read `KStream-KTable Join` or `KTable-KTable Equi-Join` sections?

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks again, the join works, but one problem remains, duplicates in join MyViews.Order(id=1, item=Apple, price=200)
MyViews.Order(id=2, item=Samsung, price=100)
MyViews.Order(id=2, item=Samsung, price=100)
MyViews.Order(id=3, item=Nokia, price=50)
MyViews.Order(id=1, item=Apple, price=200)
MyViews.Order(id=4, item=HTC, price=25)
MyViews.Order(id=3, item=Nokia, price=50)
MyViews.Order(id=4, item=HTC, price=25)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
public class MyViews {

    @Autowired
    public void buildProductView(StreamsBuilder sb) {
        final Serde<Product> productSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(new JsonSerializer<>(), new ProductDeserializer());
        final Serde<Price> valueSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(new JsonSerializer<>(), new PriceDeserializer());

        final KTable<Integer, Product> products = sb.stream("products", Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(), productSerde)).selectKey((k, v) -> v.getId())
                .toTable(Materialized.<Integer, Product, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("products-view")
                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.Integer())
                        .withValueSerde(productSerde)
                        .withCachingDisabled());

        final KTable<Integer, Price> prices = sb.stream("prices", Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(), valueSerde))
                .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(v.getId(), v))
                .toTable(Materialized.<Integer, Price, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("prices-view")
                        .withKeySerde(Serdes.Integer())
                        .withValueSerde(valueSerde)
                        .withCachingDisabled());

        final KTable<Integer, Order> join = products.join(prices, Product::getId, (l, r) ->
                new Order(l.getId(), l.getItem(), r.getPrice())
        );

        join.toStream().foreach((x, y) -> System.out.println(y));

    }
    

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class Product {
        Integer id;
        String item;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class Price {
        Integer id;
        Integer price;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    public class Order {
        Integer id;
        String item;
        Integer price;
    }
}
```